# Persistent Placeholder for input and select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, placeholder

I want to have persistent placeholders for input and select boxes.For example,

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name:" />
```

The input text box will render with placeholder 'First Name:'. Suppose when input is focused and value entered is 'Ram', then Placeholder should show as 'First Name: Ram'.If we delete the Ram, then only 'First Name:' should be there.The similar behavior should exist for Select boxes too.On selecting an option, value should be shown as "First Name: Any" (Any is value selected). Using Jquery is also fine.

Comment: Just use `<label>` elements. And if you want help with actually implementing what you're asking, try some stuff out and come back with problems...don't just ask for the whole code to be written for you. Anyways, I think the feature you're looking for is a "watermark", and there are many implementations

Comment: Feel free to provide the JavaScript you attempted to use to implement this behavior. Any jQuery you attempted is also fine.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/GUSQN/

Answer (score 1):

For accessibility, use a [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element, like this:

```
<label for='firstName'>First Name:</label>
<input type='text' id='firstName' placeholder='First name'>
```

Similarly, on `<select>` elements:

```
<label for='foo'>Foo:</label>
<select id='foo'>
    <option value='1'>Bar</option>
    <option value='2'>Baz</option>
</select>
```

You can style the label element to appear as you wish using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" value="" class="free-typing"></input>
  <input autocomplete="off" value="First Name:" class="persistent-placeholder"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
   display: block;
   max-width: 600px;
   position: relative;
   height: 36px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background-color: white;
}

.persistent-placeholder {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   color: silver;
   z-index: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; bottom: 0;
   left: 0; right: 0;
   background-color: transparent;
   border: none;
   text-indent: 5px;
   line-height: 36px;
}

.free-typing {
  z-index: 1;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: transparent;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;  bottom: 0;
   left: 0;  right: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: none;
   text-indent: 5px;
   line-height: 36px;
   font-size: 18px;
   padding-left: 100px; // this will give you indentation for the placeholder to show
}
```

For more information I wrote a post on how I achieved a similar effect.
https://medium.com/@Cuadraman/how-to-recreate-google-s-input-persistent-placeholder-8d507858e815#.1vs0vyigx